# how to use colnames() inside of a forloop to show all colnames from a list

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to loop through a list of data frames to quickly check a bunch of data all at once.

`source_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")`
got a list of csv files in my working directory

```
for (i in source_files) {
 assign(substr(i,1,nchar(i)-4), read.csv(i))
}
```

use a for loop to read all the csv files

```
for (i in source_files) {
 n <- substr(i,1,nchar(i)-4)
 glimpse(n)
 }
```

however this doesn't work. I tried it with a few functions like glimpse, colnames...etc and none of them seem to work. glimpse returns `chr "2021xxxdata"`

i want to check them before i combine them with bind_rows. any better way to do this? or a way to make this work?

Comment: It is really best if you avoid `assign()` and just keep related items in a named list. You could use `lapply(source_files, function(x) read.csv(x))` to read all the files into a list, and then you can just apply `glimpse` over that list as well. Creating variables in your global namespace automatically can easily lead to confusion and just makes programming more difficult. But if you really need to use stuff like this, you can use `get()` with a character value to get the value of the variable. `glimpse(get(n))`

Comment: @MrFlick had no idea - I am totally new to R. Thanks a lot for the tip! I will try it out.

Comment: If you are new to R then I strongly suggest you avoid `get` and `assign`. They are very un-R-like and usually just lead to headaches down the road. They have a specific use case and this is not it.